# Visual Studio 2013 project: debug assertion failures

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, assertion

I have been working on a Visual Studio project (C++) for a number of weeks and this morning I have bumped into debugging errors that prevent the executable from being launched at all. Both the compiler and the linker seem to be doing a neat job.
However, I have a  Debug Assertion Failure and the file that seems to be involved in this is in the foundation classes directory, and it's called dlgdata.cpp. The ASSERT (FALSE) statement that failed in this code snippet (which the debuggers points to)

```
HWND CDataExchange::PrepareCtrl(int nIDC)
{
ASSERT(nIDC != 0);
ASSERT(nIDC != -1); // not allowed
HWND hWndCtrl;
COleControlSite* pSite = NULL;
m_pDlgWnd->GetDlgItem(nIDC, &hWndCtrl);
if (hWndCtrl == NULL)
{
    // Could be a windowless OCX
    pSite = m_pDlgWnd->GetOleControlSite(nIDC);
    if (pSite == NULL)
    {
        TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Error: no data exchange control with ID 0x%04X.\n",        nIDC);
        ASSERT(FALSE); // that is the one 
        AfxThrowNotSupportedException();
    }
```

I am not exactly sure as to how I created this while I was creating a box to display the value of a control variable. when I ignore the failure and move on with debugging, this triggers a breakpoint and takes me to winocc.cpp, and again is the ASSERT statement to be highlighted.

```
BOOL CWnd::EnableWindow(BOOL bEnable)
{
ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd) || (m_pCtrlSite != NULL));

if (m_pCtrlSite == NULL)
    return ::EnableWindow(m_hWnd, bEnable);
else
    return m_pCtrlSite->EnableWindow(bEnable);
}
```

I might go back to a back-up, but that is several hours work away and I'd be interested in knowing how to handle these problems when they occur. Should they occur again.
Cheers, M.

Answer (score 0):

If you've hand coded the control without using the wizard(s), you're probably missing the code that instantiates the control class.  The MFC message is telling you that the control is not valid.  The trace message will tell you what it is expecting for the control's resource ID.  Make sure that's what you specified in the dialog resource.

Comment: I think I am getting to what is going on. I tend to copy text boxes (on the main control dialog) and re-name them, so that their new name makes sense to me. This messes things up when I try to make use of the control variable that is assign to these control boxes. Say: DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_STATIC_core_completed, m_aux_show_completed_C); If I change the name of the IDC_STATIC_...the previous name remains stored somewhere. Where exactly I am not sure. Perhaps this is Resource.h?